# Matplotlib 'erases' lines after setting x/y limits

Tags: python, matplotlib, axes

I'm making a plotting app which should, through a tkinter gui, allow the user to create plots to graph spectral data, and modify the plots.

I'm trying to make it so the user can change the limits of the x and y axes after data has been plotted. Looking through the mpl docs, it seems like the obvious solution is to use the `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` methods. However, if these methods are invoked after a line is plotted, the line can no longer be seen, and there are no intermediate axis ticks. Through my other widgets, I know the lines are still contained in the `lines` attribute of the axis object, they just aren't visible.

My question is, is there a way to 'set' the the axes after a line has been plotted, so that the data will adjust to it, i.e be visible after adjusting the axes, and have ticks like it did before being adjusted? I'll show images of the graph to illustrate my situation. The class definitions are rather long, so I'll just show the use of `set_xlim` and `set_ylim`

The plot before changing the axis limits:
[image: The plot before changing the axis limits]
The plot after changing the x limits:
[image: The plot after changing the x limits]

```
if all(entry.get() for entry in {self.lxlimEntry, self.rxlimEntry}):
            self.master.controller.get_plots()[self.plotVar.get()].axes[0].set_xlim(self.lxlimEntry.get(), self.rxlimEntry.get())

        if all(entry.get() for entry in {self.lylimEntry, self.rylimEntry}):
            self.master.controller.get_plots()[self.plotVar.get()].axes[0].set_ylim(self.lylimEntry.get(), self.rylimEntry.get())
```

The Entry widgets are contained in a Toplevel, instantiated by a page of the application (`master`), and the Entries are where the user inputs the new x and y limits. The `controller` is the App backend.

Comment: Does `self.lxlimEntry.get()` return a float or a string?

Comment: @DizietAsahi strings, of course, my nemesis. Casting to float fixed the issue. Thank you.